# PermissionError: [WinError 32] at os.remove()

Tags: python, excel

[image]

Since a week I have the following problem. The script below worked fine before and my collegues still can run it without any problem. But with me I get the error: PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. This occurs at the os.remove()
Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Show code, not pictures!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is a bit of a rudimentary or dumb question/suggestion but, Is the file currently open in windows? Python does not generally like to access a file that you currently have open and would explain why it works for others but not you.

Comment: It is Python that keeps the file opened. When I close the pythonscript or restart the kernel and clear all output, I can remove the file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).